# Manually checking users from a trusted domain

Tags: active-directory

How can I check a user in a trusted domain exists and after that how can I check that the same user is not enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was posted on SO, I will assume you want a programming solution.

Since you didn't specify a language, I will also assume that Powershell is acceptable.

Test if user exists in domain:

```
$netbiosdomainname = "DOMAIN"
$username = "johndoe"

try {
    [adsi]::Exists("WinNT://$netbiosdomainname/$username,user")
}
catch {
    ... user does not exist ...
}
```

See [this article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/337682/directoryentry-exists-throws-exception-for-non-existent-winnt-object) for why this needs try/catch.

Test if user enabled:

```
$user = [adsi]"WinNT://$netbiosdomainname/$username,user"

if ($user.AccountDisabled) {
    ... account is disabled ...
}
```